# Reversing strings inside parentheses

Tags: java, strings, balanced-delimiters

How can I optimize this algorithm to reverse strings inside parentheses?

```
String reverseParentheses(String s) {
    String tmpCh = new String("");
    String tmpChRe = new String("");
    String tmp = new String("");
    int l = s.length();
    int n = 0;
    int j =0;
    for(int i = 0;i<l;i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='(')
                    n++;
    }
    int T[] = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='('){
                    T[j]=i;
                    j++;
            }
    }
    j=0;
    while(n>0){
            j = T[n-1] + 1;
            while(s.charAt(j)!=')'){
                    tmpCh = tmpCh + s.charAt(j);
                    j++;
            }
            for(int q=tmpCh.length()-1;q>=0;q--)
                    tmpChRe = tmpChRe + tmpCh.charAt(q);
            tmp = s.substring(0,T[n-1]) + tmpChRe + s.substring(T[n-1]+tmpChRe.length()+2);
            s = tmp;
            n--;
            tmp = "";
            tmpCh = "";
            tmpChRe = "";
    }
    return s ;
}
```

Comment: @dhiareznov as in any examples? :)

Comment: @h.j.k. let's take "abc(de)fgh" as an input , the output is "abcedfgh"

Answer (score 3):

I consider your solution to be hard to read, and also inefficient.

### Readability

> ```
> String tmpCh = new String("");
> String tmpChRe = new String("");
> String tmp = new String("");
> int l = s.length();
> int n = 0;
> int j =0;
> ```

Of the six variables declared at the top, the only one whose meaning is obvious is `l` — and since you use `l` in only one place, I wouldn't even bother making a variable for it.

Your variable naming is problematic.  "tmp" is always meaningless as part of a local variable name; local variables are always, by definition, temporary.  Furthermore, a better way to indicate the temporary nature of these variables is to place them in the proper scope.  Instead of resetting them to empty strings at the end of your `while(n>0)` loop, declare and initialize them at the top of the loop, so that they are properly scoped:

```
// Useless assignment.  It gets reassigned right away inside the loop.
// j = 0;

// You only ever use n-1, then n is decremented at the end of the loop.
// So you might as well decrement it right away.
while (n-- > 0) {
    // Formerly j
    int parenStart = T[n] + 1;
    int parenEnd = s.indexOf(')', parenStart);

    // Formerly tmpCh
    String contents = s.substring(parenStart, parenEnd);

    // No need for tmpChRe.  No need for tmp.
    s = s.substring(0, T[n]) +
        new StringBuilder(contents).reverse() +
        s.substring(T[n] + contents.length() + 2);
}
return s;
```

Please put some spaces here:

> ```
> for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
> ```

This would be more conventional and easier to read:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
```

### Efficiency

Strings in Java are immutable.  Any time you concatenate strings using `a + b`, the compiler actually writes `new StringBuilder(a).append(b).toString();`.  That creates a lot of garbage, and it also involves copying the entire contents of both strings.  So, when you loops like this, which work build strings one character at a time, are hugely inefficient!

> ```
> while(s.charAt(j)!=')'){
>         tmpCh = tmpCh + s.charAt(j);
>         j++;
> }
> for(int q=tmpCh.length()-1;q>=0;q--)
>         tmpChRe = tmpChRe + tmpCh.charAt(q);
> ```

If you need to build a string by repeatedly appending characters, create one `StringBuilder` and append to it.  Note that `StringBuilder` also has a `.reverse()` method that would be helpful.

### Suggested solution

This solution performs all of the manipulation within one `char[]` array, so there is hardly any new memory allocated.  It also validates that the input string's parentheses are properly matched; your code would either ignore mismatches or crash with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public static String reverseParentheses(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    int[] openPosStack = new int[chars.length];
    int openPosTop = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        switch (chars[i]) {
          case '(':
            // Push the index of the open parenthesis onto the stack
            openPosStack[++openPosTop] = i;
            break;
          case ')':
            // Reverse substring from the matching open parenthesis to here
            if (openPosTop < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parenthesis mismatch");
            }
            int a, b;
            for (a = openPosStack[openPosTop--], b = i; a < b; a++, b--) {
                char swap = chars[a];
                chars[a] = chars[b];
                chars[b] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    if (openPosTop >= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parenthesis mismatch");
    }

    // Remove parentheses from output
    int o = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        switch (chars[i]) {
          case '(': case ')':
            break;
          default:
            chars[o++] = chars[i];
        }
    }
    return new String(chars, 0, o);
}
```

Comment: Very clear solution indeed, can you please write the algorithm you used? I would prefer you write some kind of comment on top of the method. Why you chose to remove parenthesis in another pass?

Comment: `reverseInsideParentheses` seem more accurate.

Comment: @CodeYogi You _could_ try to remove the parentheses at the same time as the reversal is being done, but the bookkeeping would get very nasty.

Comment: I am too naive for this but I feel strongly that method is too long and doing too much.